# cannot disable dell xps 13 9360 content adaptive brightness for FHD 1080p builtin display

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bios, firmware, dell-xps

I bought a new xps 13 9360 laptop with the basic 1080p FHD display (as opposed to the higher-res QHD one) and when I got the laptop, I immediately installed Ubuntu. However, I noticed that the brightness was automatically adjusting itself depending on how bright the applications on the screen were, and this is incredibly annoying.

A quick search online points to several Dell Community forum threads where tons of people complain that a patch was created for the QHD version, but people with FHD displays are out of luck. A Dell support representative asked me to reinstall windows and run some diagnostics, but knowing this is a firmware / BIOS issue, that clearly doesn't help. I updated the BIOS to the latest version by copying the .exe file to /boot/efi, then rebooting, and it worked fine. However, in the BIOS settings, still no option to disable the content adaptive brightness.

Is there a way to disable the content adaptive brightness for FHD 1080p display xps 13's?

Answer (score 1):

the solution to this problem, specifically for FHD, is buried in the [arch linux wiki page for dell xps 13](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(9360)). I had to reinstall windows on my dell, then update to the latest intel graphics controller, and finally download [this official dell tool](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=312K3) which changes the firmware to disable the content adaptive brightness. After that, no more annoying auto brightness changes, even after reinstalling ubuntu.

Also note many of the threads on the official dell community forum have people complaining that there's no fix for FHD, even though the one I just described (based on the excellent arch linux wiki) works perfectly, though that's because they archive the threads and don't allow new replies for some reason